# Can you perfectly line up one object with an array modifier with another object that has an array modifier?

Tags: modifiers, windows

[image]

So here's the problem.  I want the cylinders to be smack in the middle of the cubes when giving them both an array modifier.  I know one way to make that happen, is to just join them together and give the new combined mesh an array modifier.  However, in order to use the cylinders as a boolean, the cylinder has to be a separate object (unless there's something I don't know).  But when I try to line up the cylinder to be in the middle of the other cubes by adjusting the spacing, it gets gradually more OFF center.

I'm asking because I'm once again, trying to put windows in a wall (not the basic type that could be done with the archimesh tool).  A while back I saw a video in which the person did this by having a mesh in the shape of the window placed in the middle of it, and doing a boolean (difference) operation on the wall to make a hole for the window with said mesh.  The only thing was, they only made one window for their example, and I'm attempting many on a big building wall.

So hopefully my question makes sense and someone can help me out by either letting me know if I can make that happen, or giving me another method of creating windows for walls.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use constant offset inside the array in both of them

[image]

Comment: MUCH OBLIGED, PARTNER!

Comment: For information, if they don't align even when you use the same consant offset, remember to apply the scale with CTRL + A > Scale or Object > Apply > Scale